# Filter df by list of allowable combinations of column values

Tags: python, pandas

Say I have a dataframe with like this:

```
   Animal  Color
0     Dog  White
1     Cat  Black
2     Dog  Black
3     Dog  Brown
4  Rabbit  Brown
```

And I want to get all indices which match these tuples: `[('Cat', 'Black'), ('Dog', 'Brown')]`. So that would be `[1,3]` in this case.

I can't do something like `df[np.isin(df['Animal'], ['Cat', 'Dog']) & np.isin(df['Color'], ['Black', 'Brown'])]` because that would give me `[1,2,3]`

If this were just one column I would use `df[np.isin(df[col], ls)]`.

If I only cared about one tuple I could have done `df[(df[col0] == tup[0]) & (df[col1] == tup[1])]`

I just don't know how to combine the two concepts.

Comment: `df['Animal'].isin(['Cat','Dog']) & df['Color'].eq('Black')`?

Comment: I didn't mean for 'Black' to be the same over both tuples. Let me change it to be more general

Comment: @AlexanderSoare, I think you meant `df[(df[col0] == tup[0]) & (df[col1] == tup[1])]` and not `df[(df[col1] == tup[0]) & (df[col1] == tup[1])]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way with the pandas MultiIndex.  I changed the example to have a red dog:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

data = '''   Animal  Color
0     Dog  White
1     Cat  Black
2     Dog  Red
3     Dog  Brown
4  Rabbit  Brown
'''
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(data), sep='\s+', engine='python', index_col=0)

to_keep = [('Cat', 'Black'), 
           ('Dog', 'Red'),
          ]

mask = pd.MultiIndex.from_frame(df[['Animal', 'Color']]).isin(to_keep)

print(df.loc[mask])

  Animal  Color
1    Cat  Black
2    Dog    Red
```

Answer (score 1):

Let's try broadcasting:

```
mask = (df.values[:,None,:] == np.array(a)).all(-1).any(-1)

df[mask]
```

Output:

```
  Animal  Color
1    Cat  Black
3    Dog  Brown
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just create a Boolean series that will contain your logic as follows:

```
criterion = [('Cat', 'Black'), ('Dog', 'Brown')]

cond = reduce(lambda x, y: ((df['Animal'] == x[0]) & (df['Color'] == x[1])) | ((df['Animal'] == y[0]) & (df['Color'] == y[1])), criterion)

print(df[cond])
```

Outputs:

```
  Animal  Color
1    Cat  Black
3    Dog  Brown
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `for loop` to pull the indices :

```
df.loc[[ind 
        for ind, a, b in zip(df.index, df.Animal, df.Color)
        if (a, b) in keep]]

Animal  Color
1   Cat Black
3   Dog Brown
```

If the indices are not important you could `set index` and `reset index` :

```
df.set_index(["Animal", "Color"], append=False, drop=False).loc[keep].reset_index(
    drop=True
)

  Animal    Color
0   Cat     Black
1   Dog     Brown
```